# Representing relative stock price predictions in portfolio optimization

Tags: portfolio-optimization, statistical-finance, statistical-significance

I wanted to ask a simple question in representing mathematical concepts/terms into the portfolio optimization utility functions.

I have never worked with these in production environment so I am very likely to be wrong, please feel free to disagree, provide some insights.

In Statistical Arbitrage, people are basically trying to bet based on the relative performance/relationship of the baskets of stocks (assume only in equities/Delta 1 space).

From pair's trading point of view, one attempts to find a pair of stocks that are in same sector/statistical clusters, and identify whether those selected pairs have cointegrated relationships, and bet that in the longer run these relationships will converge, as the pairs are identified to be stationary.

Extending this idea from a single stock - single stock pair, I was thinking of applying these relative performance alpha into the multiple stocks and representing them in "alpha" for mean-variance portfolio optimization purposes.

First of all, does applying mean variance optimization to medium frequency strategy (i.e., average holding period of a day to week) makes sense?

Also, how would one go about representing these predicted "relative price relationship among the stocks" into this optimization model?
* some of the thoughts I had was, representing the relative stock predictions into decile, assign max alpha (e.g., 5%), and assign this 5% back to the stocks based on the decile. i.e., from 0-10% assign alpha of +5%, from 90-100% assign alpha of -5%, etc. But this brings another problem when I try to combine multiple factors into the optimization.

I appreciate your intuition and time in advance.
Thank you.